# dynamic SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()?

Tags: sosl, sobjecttype

I have a Lightning component with a search bar that uses Apex to search Cases, and another that searches Opportunities. For example:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Case> searchCases(String searchKey) 
{
    String name = '%' + searchKey + '%';
    if(!Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()){
        return null;
    }else 
    {
        return 
        [   
            SELECT Account.Name,Subject,Status,CreatedDate, Contact.Name, Priority
            FROM Case
            WHERE Subject LIKE :name OR Account.Name LIKE :name
            ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC
        ];
    }
}
```

Now, I want to provide search integration with custom objects, which the admin will be able to specify from a pulldown menu when they drop the component on the page in page builder. I built a class to create the list of custom objects, and I've wired that into the .design file of the component. So now, my search bar component will be able to access the name of the custom object -- let's say `Applicants__c`, for example.

[image]

Now, I'm creating a the search bar functionality where I'll be searching the Name field of the custom object. I'll call the apex method, providing the searchKey and the name of the custom object. I need help figuring out how to use that dynamic custom object name to check for accessibility, and to execute the search. So the first part...

I tried this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Object> searchRecords(String searchKey, String custObj) 
{
    String name = '%' + searchKey + '%';
    if(!custObj.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()){
        return null;
    }else ...
```

And got this error:

> Variable does not exist: SObjectType

I also tried specifying the incoming param as an SObject and an SObjectType, with no luck. Same error when I try to push to scratch org.

The docs say you can't bind the FROM aspect of a SOQL search, so I figure I'll build the string dynamically. Here's my best shot, which is compiling ok.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Object> searchRecords(String searchKey, String custObj) 
{
    String name = '%' + searchKey + '%';
    if(!custObj.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()){
        return null;
    }else 
    {
        String searchQuery = 'FIND :name IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING :' + custObj + '(Name,LastModifiedDate)';
        return search.query(searchQuery);
    }
}
```

Any tips welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need on the Describe side is the method [`Schema.describeSObjects()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm#!), which can be called with an arbitrary object name or names:

```
if (Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{ custObj })[0].isAccessible()) {
```

(Handling for failure cases omitted).

It's true that you cannot bind the `FROM` in a SOQL query, but you certainly can build the entire query dynamically. (You switched to SOSL in the second example; was that expediency or objective?) As an illustration:

```
return Database.query(
    String.format(
        'SELECT Name FROM {0} WHERE Name LIKE \'\'{1}\'\' ' +
        'ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC'
        new List<String> {
            custObj,
            '%' + searchKey + '%'
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks @David, that's sleek. RE: SOSL... I'll probably use SOQL here, but in another handler, I'll be using hasRecordId and doing a SOSL search on all fields in those custom objects to pull up related records.

Comment: Now that I'm working with your code, I don't understand what you're doing with the new List<String>.

Comment: `String.format()` takes a `List<String>` of parameters to use in populating merge fields (like `{0}`, `{1}`). The format parameters for this dynamic SOQL query are the object (`{0}`) and the search key (`{1}`). (I omitted it, but the search key should be escaped too).

Comment: One can do dynamic SOQL by simply concatenating strings, but I prefer to write out the template structure and perform substitution with `String.format()` for clarity.

Comment: Oh... thanks for the lesson. I've never seen that before.

Comment: Key trap with `String.format()`, by the way, is doubling your single quotes, an artifact of the underlying Java [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

Comment: Is describeSObjects() still slower than pulling from Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get( objectName ) ?

Comment: I actually don't know, @Ronnie. I have not benchmarked them or followed that discussion.

Comment: I know at one point it was an issue - i guess i will need to check sometime and see. I still typically pull statically the all object at beginning of a process that needs it - use it across multiple methods and only need to reference a map.. i guess application is everything Thanks @David Reed

Answer (score 0):

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Object> searchRecords(String searchKey, String custObj) 
{
    String name = '%' + searchKey + '%';
    if(!Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get( custObj ).getSObjectType().getDescribe().isAccessible()){
        return null;
    }else ...
```

this should get the what you need it

OR Simply

```
public static Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> allObjects { get; set; }

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Object> searchRecords( String srchKey, String objectName ){

     if( allObjects == null ){
         allObjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
     }

     if( allObjects.containsKey( objectName ) && allObjects.get( objectName ).getDescribe().isAccessible()){
          ......
     }
     else { 
          .....

     }
}
```